# Drag image javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

here is two events. With first event:drag gets element id.
Second event: drop must move picture where is cursor, but not doing it...

Please help me to correct that drop event.. I know I can use jquery, but I just have little time.
I just somehow need in drop event where is if((parseInt(id, 10) > 0) || (id==0)) change picture cords, but i dont know what to use. 
part of code is here:

```
   function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var id=ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
var CursorY=ev.pageY;
var CursorX=ev.pageX;
var posx = 0;
var posy = 0;
if (ev.pageX || ev.pageY)     {
    posx = ev.pageX;
    posy = ev.pageY;
}
else if (ev.clientX || ev.clientY)    {
    posx = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
        + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    posy = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
        + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
var element = document.getElementById(id);
var element2 = document.getElementById("insert_box");
var name = element.getAttribute("name");
var w=document.getElementById(id).offsetWidth;
var h=document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight;

//alert(w+" "+h )

if((parseInt(id, 10) > 0) || (id==0))
{
   //element.style.top=posy;
   //element.style.left=posx;
}else 
{
    element2.innerHTML = element2.innerHTML + "<div class='drag'><img style='position:absolute' draggable='true' name="+name+" id='"+i+"' ondragstart='drag(event)' src='Images/"+name+"'></div>";
    var element_ID = document.getElementById(i); 
    i++;
} 
}
```

All code here:
http://pastebin.com/MwaVpzL5

Here is picture:
[image]
where is left you can drag image into box in right and when creates new image and when I need to move created image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your able to use [jquery](http://jquery.com) then it will make you life an aweful lot easier as [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com) has several methodsof use

[jqueryui draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) will do your dragging and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) will do your targets